# Finding linear path sections in a graph in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I need to partition an acyclic graph into linear sections. Each section will be a linear path consisting of at least one node. Linear sections cannot contain any branching.

For example, here is an example graph:

```
library(igraph); 
dor = data.frame( from = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
    to = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7) )
g = graph_from_data_frame(dor)
plot(g)
```

[image: Example graph]

In this graph, there are 4 linear sections:

```
1
3 -> 5
2 -> 4
6 -> 7
```

How can I partition a graph into linear path sections?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want to do is this.  If a node has more than one incoming edge, delete all incoming edges. If a node has more than one outgoing edge, delete all outgoing edges. So my proposed solution ... counts the incident edges and deletes them if there are too many.

```
## Your original data
library(igraph)
dor = data.frame( from = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
    to = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7) )
g = graph_from_data_frame(dor)


g2 = g
TooManyOut = which(sapply(incident_edges(g2, V(g2), mode="out"), length) > 1)
for(TMO in TooManyOut) {
    g2 = delete_edges(g2, attr(incident_edges(g2, V(g2), mode="out")[[TMO]], "vnames"))
}
TooManyIn = which(sapply(incident_edges(g2, V(g2), mode="in"), length) > 1)
for(TMI in TooManyIn) {
    g2 = delete_edges(g2, attr(incident_edges(g2, V(g2), mode="in")[[TMI]], "vnames"))
}
plot(g2)
```

[image: Reduced Graph]

Of course, you can get which nodes are connected using `components`.